# How to add infragistics scrollbar in MVC

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have created a grid using infragistics grid. In MVC to display data from database . but unable to add scrollbar to it.

Comment: modify the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` property in CSS when it exceeds a particular width and height respectively.

Comment: Please put the code to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Set `height` to your grid, and if the data fills the container, then it would overflow and show a scrollbar.